# MIP - Large Piecewise Linear Constraints Over Continuous Intervals

Tags: optimization, numerical-modelling, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming, numerical-limitations

I'm currently trying to run a MIP (have access to both Gurobi and CBC) with a piecewise linear function having ~200 intervals for each of the ~30 x values I have. I am using the standard decomposition to linearize the function. I.e.

having a binary variable $y_i$ for each interval $D_i = [a, b - eps]$ s.t. if $x \in D$ then $f(x) = s_i$ where $eps > Feasability\text{_}Tolerance$. The default feasibility tolerance is 1e-6.

Note that $D_{i+1} = [b, c - eps]$

Here's what I've tried:

1. I've tried to use the above formulation alone and somehow am able to end up with values of x that are in two adjacent intervals, but thought that offsetting the upper bound by eps would resolve this. So I end up with something like $f(x) = s_i + s_{i + 1}$. Even with CBC, this approach converges relatively quickly, though inaccurate.
2. As an extension to (1), I added a constraint $\sum_i s_i == 1$ to try to enforce that x only fall into one interval, but both solvers failed to converge here.
3. A slightly different approach: I first reduced my function to roughly ~50 intervals as an approximation and for all intervals $D_i, i>1$, I have two binary variables $y_i$ (same as above) and $b_i$, so $f_1 == y_1 s_i$ and then for all $i > 1$, I have

$$
y_{i-1} + y_i <= 2 - (1 - b_i)$$$$
y_{i-1} + y_i >= 2 - 2 ( 1 - b_i)$$
$$f_i == s_i (y_i - b_i)$$

so here $b_i = 1$ implies that x is in both intervals, so we use the score from the previous interval. Otherwise the $y_i$ will do the deciding. I'm actually able to get decent performance with Gurobi here (~1min) but CBC didn't converge in 20mins.

Conclusion: I'm not sure if the size of the PWL function I'm working with is impractical, but I feel like there should be something I can do with (1) to find a model that can be efficiently solved, but I'm struggling to find an efficient approach to mitigate the numerical inaccuracies I'm seeing.

Comment: Are you using [SOS constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_ordered_set)?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the paper from Vielma et al. (https://doi.org/10.1287/opre.1090.0721) to gather more insights on how to represent your function as a piecewise-linear (PWL) model in a MILP problem.

In addition, this series of blog posts may be helpful during your implementation:

https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2019/02/piecewise-linear-functions-and.html?m=1

https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2019/02/piecewise-linear-functions-and_22.html?m=1